# Does the negation have to be true to disprove something?

Tags: logic

I found a case that shows that the implication is not true, so I'm trying to disprove it. I always see it done by proving the negation of the implication.

Does the negation have to be true to disprove something?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? To disprove an implication $P \Rightarrow Q$ you need to give an example where $P$ is true and $Q$ is false. That's the only way an implication can be false.

Comment: Well, in negation, the quantifiers switch from `exists` to `for all` and vice versa. When it isn't necessarily for all.

Comment: Typically to disprove something you use a proof by contradiction or use the contrapositive. It's more intuitive to prove a positive statement than a negative.

Comment: Disprove from contrapositive? That can't be right because if a statement is true, then its contrapositive is true

Comment: @macdonjo Ah you have an implication with quantifiers. Can you give a particular example so that people can understand what you're asking?

Comment: Not looking for help with the statement I'm working on, but just an answer to: `Does the negation have to be true to disprove something?`

Comment: @macdonjo Any proposition is true if and only if its negation is false. Is that what you mean? "I found a case that shows that the implication is not true, so I'm trying to disprove it." Ah ... no, just because you have a case where it's false doesn't mean it's *always* false. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "disprove" or *refute* $\varphi$ means to prove $\lnot \varphi$; nothing change is $\varphi$ is a *conditional* : $P \rightarrow Q$.

If with "a case that shows that the implication is not true" you mean that you have found a case showing that $\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x))$ is not true, this means that its *negation* is true.

We have that :

> $\lnot \forall x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x))$

is equivalent to :

$\exists  x \lnot (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x))$.

If we note that $P \rightarrow Q$ is equivalent to : $\lnot (P \land \lnot Q)$, we have that the above formula is equivalent to :

> $\exists  x (P(x) \land \lnot Q(x))$

which is the negation of $\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x))$.

Thus, to prove $\exists  x (P(x) \land \lnot Q(x))$ means to disprove $\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x))$.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an implication of the form $P \rightarrow Q$, then we can write a corresponding truth table. If you have found a counter example, that is, a witness to non-implication, you can show that your "example" (counter example) is a witness to non-implication. This is typically sufficient for disproving a statement. However, if you would like to formally prove that $P \rightarrow Q$ is incorrect, that is, there is a witness to non-implication, you can show its negation  ~$(P \rightarrow Q)$ is true under all interpretations.

It beats the falsity of the implication to death, but works.

As an example, consider the statement "if $c|ab$, then $c|b$, or  $c|a$ for all $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$. Clearly, we can find a counter example. That is, let $a=2, b=2, c=4$. Then, there exists integers $a,b,c$ for which it is not the case that if $c|ab$, then $c|b$, or  $c|a$ for all $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$.